# How to change the class name based on the textbox value

Tags: jquery

I have more textbox controls in my page and when the text is null the CSS or class should change, and when there is some text I need to change the current CSS or class. I am not getting the logic how to do this. My design code is like this:

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server" CssClass="field" Width="150px"></asp:TextBox>
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtLastName" runat="server" CssClass="field" Width="150px"></asp:TextBox>
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtemail" runat="server" CssClass="field" Width="150px"></asp:TextBox>
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtpassword" runat="server" CssClass="field" Width="150px"></asp:TextBox>
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtconfirmpassword" runat="server" CssClass="field" Width="150px"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: Your code does not appear to have been included; Please edit your question to include the code, to make it easier to understand the issue.

Comment: And what's your mark-up? And, incidentally, there is **no** `textbox` element in html. There never has been. Are you using `textarea` or `input type="text"`?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#element').keypress(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == '') {
        $(this).removeClass('myClass');
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('myClass');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
$('#myInput').keyup(function() {
    if ($(this).val()) {
        $(this).removeClass('empty-class');
        $(this).addClass('full-class');
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass('full-class');
        $(this).addClass('empty-class');
    }
});
```

Working example at http://jsfiddle.net/z4TQY/1/

I've assumed you want two different classes for the two states, rather than a single class which is added or removed.

BTW, this is working on `keyup` rather than `keypress` because the latter fires *before* the contents of the text box get changed by that keypress.

Also, for more consistent behaviour register the same function against `.change()` so that your classes mirror any changes that weren't the result of a key up event.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this (I could not test it right now):

```
$("#textboxid").change(function(){ 
  if($(this).val() != ''){
    $(this).addClass('cssclass');
  } else {
    $(this).removeClass('cssclass');
  }
});
```

Hope it helps.